# How to use 2 different condition substitute for each other in the same SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having this issue
Now, I'm having this table

| Code | FirstNo | LastNo | Date_input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1234 | 12 | 34 | 2022/06/06 |
| ABCD5678 | 56 | 78 | 2022/07/07 |
| ABCD9111 | 91 | 11 | 2022/07/07 |
| DEF1234 | 12 | 34 | 2022/06/06 |
| DEF5678 | 56 | 78 | 2022/07/07 |

Then, I want to return 2 random number (these 2 number is from 00 to 99) which will be taken from front-end. Lets call them Random1 and Random2.
Now, when the query running, it will run from record 1 --> final

If whenever the FirstNo = Random1, then the next record will take the condition of FirstNo = Random2. Then, at the next record, it will return to get the condition of FirstNo = Random1.

For example, Random1 = 56, Random2 = 91, and the table as above

First record: FirstNo != 56, move to the next row.

Second record: FirstNo = 56.

Third record: (Because of at the previous record, FirstNo equal Random1 (56), this record will get Random2 instead) FirstNo = 91.

Fourth record: Back to Random1, .....

So, I'm figuring out something like:

```
SELECT * FROM CODE_DEX WHERE FirstNo = @Random1
SELECT * FROM CODE_DEX WHERE FirstNo = @Random2
```

I haven't have any idea how to joining these 2. I can create a column ISTRUE or something to Declare and Set in SQL, but I don't think I can use IF in the middle of the sql query.

Thank you so much

Comment: Your example does not make sense to me -- what is the order of these records -- in your text you say the order is date_input but then the 4th one listed is in the wrong spot -- also what do you do when the date input is the same -- just random order those?  --- looks to me like the order in the example is by Code not Date

Comment: I cannot input the real data, so it is made up data

Comment: what if you had the two random numbers found non consecutively between the rows? what would you expect? @aqsakd Can you add an expected output table to your post?

Comment: Then you need made up data that makes sense or we can't understand what you want -- do you want to read ordered by date or code?

Comment: @lemon it only matter if the FirstNo = Random1 is match, then the next record will be FirstNo = Random2
After that, it will continue to use the condition FirstNo = Random1 until this condition is match again no matter FirstNo = Random2 is correct or not

Comment: So rows need to be consecutive, though is your final output the result of a selection, an insertion, a filtering, can you provide more details?

Comment: @Hogan the order is not the point, I will delete this part just now
the problem is I'm having no idea how to use 2 condition substitute to each other

Comment: order is the point -- but you can change it in the solution I gave -- that is the OVER part of the LAG clause

Comment: @lemon it is a SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

Based on stated requirement

*If the prior row value for FirstNo ordered by date is Random1 then return random2 for FirstNo*

You would do that like this in SQL

```
SELECT Code, 
       CASE WHEN LAG(FirstNo,1) OVER (ORDER BY Date_Input) = Random1 
            THEN Random2
            ELSE FirstNo END AS FirstNo,
       LastNo,
       Date_input
FROM sometableyoudidnotname
ORDER BY Date_input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select:

- next value, with the [`LEAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) window function
- previous value, with the [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function

then filter out all rows which don't have "*Random1*" and "*Random2*" values in consecutive rows:

```
SET @Random1 = 56;
SET @Random2 = 91;

WITH cte AS (
       SELECT *,
              LAG(FirstNo)  OVER(ORDER BY Code, Date_input) AS PrevNo,
              LEAD(FirstNo) OVER(ORDER BY Code, Date_input) AS NextNo
       FROM tab
)
SELECT Code,
       FirstNo,
       LastNo,
       Date_input
FROM cte 
WHERE (FirstNo = @Random1 AND NextNo = @Random2)
   OR (FirstNo = @Random2 AND PrevNo = @Random1)
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xEiLANfF8CzuxVnXmaLHq/1).

Comment: Thanks
have to take a look at LAG and LEAD

Comment: Added some references to those two window functions inside the answer.

Comment: wait... filtering out rows was part of the requirements?

Comment: Mh actually I don't know: this is just my understanding of the problem, I may be wrong about it. As if he wanted to retrieve infos of all consecutive rows that have those two numbers. @Hogan

Comment: not sure the OP knows.  His example is not even ordered by Date_input